# Is this a bug in MySQL query parsing?

Tags: mysql

I was running some queries, and ran into something which I think looks like a MySQL bug.  I ran the following query:

```
select s.id, a.name as a_name, s.label, st.name as st_name,
-- substr(f.name FROM 1 FOR locate('cl', f.name)-2),
-- substr(f.name FROM locate('cl', f.name)-2 FOR 1),
substr(f.name FROM locate('cl', f.name)),
count(1)
from table_sf sf,
table_f f,
table_s s,
table_a a,
table_st st
where f.id = sf.f_id
and s.id = sf.s_id
and s.a_id = a.id
and s.st_id = st.id
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
having count(1) != 2;
```

By default, MySQL assigns column names when you don't specify one on calculated fields.  Usually, it's just the field's full "formula", e.g., `count(1)` for the last field in the query above.  However, it seems adding comments inside the query throws MySQL off.  The results are correct, but the field name is completely wrong.  These are the column headers I get:

```
 id    name         label         name       -- substr(f.name FROM 1 FOR locate('cl', f.name)-2),       count(1)
```

Notice that the 5th column gets as name the **first** comment, not even the adjoining one.  And it did recognize that there's two comments, because it only assigned the first one as the column name for the next calculated field without an alias.  Is this expected behavior?  Or is this a MySQL bug?  I'm running MySQL 5.1.63, using SequelPro as client on a OS X.

**Update:**
Also tried it on a MySQL 5.4.3 install, and the field shows correctly there.  Maybe it's a bug in the 5.1.x codebase?

Comment: Can you please tell how you run the query? Is mysql command line client or some other tool?

Comment: @woz: In this case it seems plausible. Please actually read the question.

Comment: @Dukeling: Thanks, and good point. OP: please reduce the code in your question.

Comment: Deleted my comment because I'm not sure whether it's quite the same, but [here it is again](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9562).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, did some research, and it seems I found the original bug.  It was reported some time ago in 5.0, and it was only targeted to fix until 5.2.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25224

So, it seems that if you're running MySQL 5.1.x, you're going to encounter this issue.  MySQL's response, it seems, was just to upgrade to a newer version.